# Returning data from Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

My main goal is to use PDF.js and send the parsed PDF data to front-end. PDF.js library works on promises and returns data from the file by page number. This is where my problem is. I am not very familiar with promises and making loops in them to return data.
My code at the moment looks like this:

```
var pdf = path.join(__dirname, '../../testoutput.pdf');
    pdfJsLib.getDocument(pdf).then(function(doc){
        var promises = [];
        for(i = 1; i <= doc.numPages; i++){
            //promises.push(doc.getPage(i));
            doc.getPage(i).then(function(page){
                promises.push(page.getTextContent());

                var response = [];
                if(i == doc.numPages + 1){
                    var promiseLimiter = promises.length;
                    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
                        response.push(data[0]);
                        if(promiseLimiter == doc.numPages){
                            res.status(200).json(response);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

I am trying to push page.getTextContent() information to an array and send the array as an response but I understand that I am doing this the wrong way.
Any ideas how to make the loop work correctly with promises in this case?

Comment: Promise.all, must be out of for, whw is ended and fullfilled promises arr

Comment: what is getTextContext()

Comment: getTextContext() is a function that is provided by the PDF.js lib and you can extract text data from the pdf page by that. It returns you data about the words and their position and styles. 
Data from that usually looks something like this: https://pastebin.com/tT7gSu2a.
This also should be used as promise page.getTextContent().then(function(content){//do something with content})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you'd want to do something like this

```
var pdf = path.join(__dirname, '../../testoutput.pdf');
pdfJsLib.getDocument(pdf).then(function(doc){
    var promises = [];
    var promiseLimiter ;
    for(i = 1; i <= doc.numPages; i++){
        //promises.push(doc.getPage(i));
        var p = doc.getPage(i).then(function(page){
            return page.getTextContent();

            var response = [];
            if(i == doc.numPages + 1){
                promiseLimiter = promises.length;
            }
        })
        promises.push(p);
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
                    if(promiseLimiter == doc.numPages){
                        res.status(200).json(data);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: If you try to go through the promises array out of the then() it is empty. So basically you need to implement some kind of loop with the promise and it's returned data. And this is the spot that my knowledge is in a stop.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem. The promiseLimiter if statement in the for loop and in the Promise.all is unnecessary. When they are removed the data is sent in a correct way I itended.

Comment: how could promise.all be uneccessary?

Comment: I meant the if statement in the promise.all().